# How to compare two columns

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

df1

```
 V1              V2
ec:2.7.11.1     hsa:9344
ec:2.7.11.1     hsa:5894
ec:2.7.11.1     hsa:673
ec:2.7.12.2     hsa:5607
ec:2.7.11.24    hsa:5598
ec:2.7.11.25    hsa:9020
ec:2.7.11.24    hsa:51701
ec:2.3.1.250    hsa:64840
```

df2

```
 V1             
9344
5607
9020
64840
```

I want to get:

```
  V1              V2
ec:2.7.11.1     hsa:9344
ec:2.7.12.2     hsa:5607
ec:2.7.11.25    hsa:9020
ec:2.3.1.250    hsa:64840
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:
Data :

```
df=read.table(text=" V1              V2
ec:2.7.11.1     hsa:9344
              ec:2.7.11.1     hsa:5894
              ec:2.7.11.1     hsa:673
              ec:2.7.12.2     hsa:5607
              ec:2.7.11.24    hsa:5598
              ec:2.7.11.25    hsa:9020
              ec:2.7.11.24    hsa:51701
              ec:2.3.1.250    hsa:64840",h=T)
df2=read.table(text="V1             
9344
5607
9020
64840",h=T)
```

Then use `sub()` to remove the non-digit symbols during the comparison.

```
 df[sub("\\D*","",df$V2) %in% df2$V1,]
                V1        V2
    1  ec:2.7.11.1  hsa:9344
    4  ec:2.7.12.2  hsa:5607
    6 ec:2.7.11.25  hsa:9020
    8 ec:2.3.1.250 hsa:64840
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `paste0()` on `df2$V1`

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
" V1              V2
ec:2.7.11.1     hsa:9344
ec:2.7.11.1     hsa:5894
ec:2.7.11.1     hsa:673
ec:2.7.12.2     hsa:5607
ec:2.7.11.24    hsa:5598
ec:2.7.11.25    hsa:9020
ec:2.7.11.24    hsa:51701
ec:2.3.1.250    hsa:64840")
df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"V1             
9344
5607
9020
64840")
df3 <- data.frame(V2=paste0("hsa:", df2$V1))
merge(df, df3)
```

or in one line:

```
merge(df, data.frame(V2=paste0("hsa:", df2$V1)))
```